# Mysql- left join

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, `T1(C1,C2)`, `T2(C1,C2)`, `T3(C1,C2)`,and I want to select rows from `T1` that only occur in `T1` not in `T2`, `T3`.
Now I just use the `left join` to do this.

```
SELECT C1,C2
FROM   T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.C1=T2.C2 AND T1.C2=T2.C2
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T1.C1=T3.C2 AND T1.C3=T2.C2
WHERE T2.C1 IS NULL AND T3.C1 IS NULL;
```

But the problem is, how to improve the performance when the database is quite large(e.g. rows>10000000 in three table). Using `LEFT JOIN`the query takes too long...

Comment: Are there indexes on T1(C1,C2) , T2(C1,C2) and T3(C1,C2)?

Comment: Define too long? Want to share the Execution plan( profile+explain)?

Comment: You don't know what the bottleneck is. How many records are produced by this? Did you use `EXPLAIN` and `profiling` to see what the optimizer does and what MySQL and OS do in order to execute and send your query? What does too long mean? In IT we have units to measure size and time, can you express what too long means in seconds?

Comment: Questions about query performance ALWAYS require, as a minimum, CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, and the results of the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: @Mjh Actually I have stop the execution when the duration was longer than 2000 seconds. And the query I actually used is more complicate than that I have written. Table T1,T2,T3 are all subqueries that also involve in large table. Will it be faster, if I first get the results from these three subqueries  into new table T1,T2,T3, than do the left join?

Comment: @DragandDrop Actually I stopped the execution when the duration was longer than 2000 seconds...

Comment: Still no `explain`, no `profiling`, no `create table`.. can't help you here mate, good luck.

Comment: @RaymondNijland No indexes on tables. Can you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

Three things that immediately jump to mind are:
   - Indexes on the fields used for the joins
   - SELECT only the data you really need
   - give your database server lots of memory

Answer (score -1):

A subquery can help you here. You can save additional costs of left joins this way.

```
SELECT 
C1,C2
FROM  
T1
WHERE
C1 NOT IN (
SELECT C1 FROM T2
UNION ALL
SELECT C1 FROM T3
);
```

Comment: Can you point us to the document that explains how subquery is faster than a left / inner join? From your answer, all I can surmise is that you *think* subquery is faster than a join, but there's absolutely no evidence or proof why.

Comment: Yes @Mjh, this is what I think. I have tried this approach on very large datasets and it works better than a join.

Comment: @lili-zhu can you please check timings for this approach?

Comment: No, it doesn't work better. Your word, without any proof, means nothing. Sorry. Also you won't find any proof because the optimizer doesn't care if you write a query as subquery or join, because one can be written as the other. Your answer is just.. stabbing in the dark with no proof to back it up.